# Android studio 3.1 version image assert is not working on my android studio toll Any one help me

Tags: image, version, assert

[image]

Android studio 3.1.0 version image assert doesn't work my side

Answer (score 0):

[Adaptive icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html) were introduced in Android 8 (SDK 26).

I'm guessing that you selected Adaptive Icons when you started to create your launcher icon.  You'll either need to create a standard icon or update the SDK version in your app.gradle file.